# Table Coming out from Div - IE Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I am a UI developer.
My issue is I kept a table inside 2 `divs`. But the table is coming out of the `div` in IE8.

In Firefox, it works smoothly. But IE its killing me.

Please help me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6N5Z.jpg

Comment: Can you post your html/css code?

Comment: without code it's difficult to get help, paste your html/cs to jsfiddle.net

Comment: have you set the container holding the div to have the css property overflow:hidden; ??

Comment: Here is Jsfiidle Code : http://jsfiddle.net/9QCTu/

Pls Help me Out.

@lukeocom -- No I didnt set Overflow Hidden

Comment: It seems as though you have many errors in your markup. Table cells arent closed properly, hanging tags etc. Run your code through a validator such as http://validator.w3.org and try fix some of the errors. This may help resolve your issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to your css is a temporary solution:

```
.rightPane{overflow-x:scroll;}
```

I say temporary as there are plenty of errors in your html. Such as surrounding an entire table in a `<h1>` tag. I reccomend you run your source through a validation service and fix the errors. The cleaner code will then be easier to fix and a more reliable fix too.

your updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9QCTu/1/

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukeocom !!! But in IE that Bg_white ang blue color background is not extending accrding to table why ??

Comment: again this is something that would be easier to resolve if your markup was correctly formatted or at least cleaner. You may be able to solve that issue by changing the width of the table or its z-index or its overflow property. But without well formed html code it's hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks. Let me Try to format it well. Its a Sharepoint Project and hence having lots of framework modifications which effecet my html.